# Windows RDP Resolution Changes When RDP Client is minimized?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp

When using RDP to control a Win10 machine, the initial session starts in full resolution(expected behavior). When the client is minimized and then restored, the resolution in the client automatically becomes 800x600.

edit:
The client has en external 4k monitor connected. The behavior described above is only present when the client has the monitor connected. When the monitor is removed, the RDP display is as expected.

Comment: Hi. Just to be sure, the remote resolution become 800x600, or the windowed RDP windows become 800x600 with scrollbar ?

Comment: The remote session resolution changes(full screen)

Comment: So the server is Win10, but what OS is the host machine running...also Win10? You're using the default RDP client, MSTSC.exe?

Comment: Client side is win 7 with default RDP client.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adjusting the Display Configuration on the Display tab to the notch just below "Full Screen" (1920x1080).

The initial window is 1080, but once you make it full screen or stretched to your current resolution it will fill out.

A minor annoyance for sure when connecting to a workstation operating at 4K, but easily circumvented until a fix is implemented.